# How do I keep mysql databases in sync on 2 computers with Dropbox?

Tags: mysql, mamp

I do I keep local development MySql databases in sync on 2 computers.

I have MAMP installed and currently the development files are synced with dropbox, I would like to do the same with mysql databases.

Thank you

PS: Maybe the question should be, how to I keep MAMP sync on 2 computers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not sync your MySQL databases using Dropbox as explained here - https://askubuntu.com/questions/518546/is-syncing-a-mysql-database-with-dropbox-this-easy-and-is-it-a-backup-solution

You can sync MAMP folders but without db folders - http://simon-davies.name/mamp/syncing-mamp-with-dropbox